# Font and Encoding for Spanish And Latin American Spanish with itext creatFont

Tags: java, encoding, itext, locale

**Looking for Font and Encoding mapping for Spanish And Latin American Spanish**

For example- Korean

```
 BaseFont korean = BaseFont.createFont("HYGoThic-Medium", "UniKS-UCS2-H", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

- Font -> HYGoThic-Medium
- Encoding -> UniKS-UCS2-H

using: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf

Please give your suggestions for Spanish & Latin American Spanish.

Comment: I do read it, before sending the invite. I know, it won't get accepted. But, it's worth trying & following you to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You need a special font for Korean because Korean has its own alphabet (each character is a syllabe composed of a vowel and one or two consonants). Spanish, whether it's European or Latin-American doesn't have many special characters. You basically need a Latin set, and support for these extra characters: á, é, í, ó, ú, ¿, ¡, ü, ñ.

Most of the "typical" Microsoft fonts such as Arial, Times-Roman, and so on, support these characters. Your question is strange in the sense that you know how to create a font that supports a "special" character set such as the Korean one, but you don't know how to create a font that supports a "normal" character set as the Spanish one.

Just try:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(font, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Where `font` is the path to a `.ttf` file such as:

- `c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf`
- `resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf`
- ...

Read the tutorial [Using fonts in PDF and iText](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tutorial/using-fonts-pdf-and-itext) on the official web site to learn more about different fonts and languages.

Comment: Main confusion was with handling with special characters. This is more clear now.